# Computer Vision Recognize Text API can't recognize Traditional Chinese

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

The local container seems only support English.
Any one can help?

“
 Important
The Recognize Text container currently works only with English.
“
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/computer-vision-how-to-install-containers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OCR API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text#ocr-optical-character-recognition-api) instead as it supports a large set of languages, including Chinese (Simplified) and Chinese (Traditional) as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/language-support#text-recognition)